# Trigger method/script when using "use" keyword

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to execute a method/script when the `use` keyword is used in php/laravel?

I have a class and a trait

I want to execute a method within the trait whenever it's used in a class (just once)
I figured that doing so in the trait's constructor would work and it did, until I came across a class with only static methods.

For eg:

```
class A {
   use B;
   public static function hello() {
      return "hello";
   }
}

trait B {
   function i_want_to_execute_on_use_keyword_but_just_once() {
      return "Executing important things";
   }
}

A::hello(); ---\> B's method should execute before this\`
```

Is there something in php/laravel that will let me execute this type of behaviour?

Note: In my actual scenario, I'll need to run reflection on the class that uses the trait.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to instantiate the class to access its methods from a static method, even coming from a trait. Obs: I made the method public to be accessed as a method.

```
class A {
   use B;
   public static function hello() {
      $static = new static();
      $static->i_want_to_execute_on_use_keyword_but_just_once();
      return "hello";
   }
}

trait B {
   public function i_want_to_execute_on_use_keyword_but_just_once() {
      return "Executing important things";
   }
}
```

All Traits methods/functions are accessible via $this (respecting the OO hierarchy).

I don't know the context of your situation/application, but I believe there are better ways to work with this type of situation, as a service class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vitor
Unfortunately, this calls the function from the class. I need the method present in the trait to be executed automatically.
Service classes would involve a different flow altogether for my use-case.